# Receiving an error in Oracle - Regarding subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving the error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 51 Column: 3

[image: SQL Code]

[image: Error Message]

```
SELECT *
FROM EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum
  (SELECT ems.vw_tal_patron.ptnid, ems.vw_tal_patron.firstname, ems.vw_tal_patron.lastname, ems.vw_tal_ptncard.lastmoddate, ems.vw_tal_userauditaction.action
   FROM ems.vw_tal_patron, ems.vw_tal_ptncard, ems.vw_tal_userauditaction 
   WHERE ems.vw_tal_patron.ptnid = Ems.vw_tal_ptncard.ptnid
   AND ems.vw_tal_ptncard.lastmoddate BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/24/2021 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('04/24/2021 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
   AND ems.vw_tal_userauditaction.action = 'CREATE USER')
WHERE EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum.anntypedesc = 'Sign-Up Date' 
AND EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum.anndate BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/24/2021 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('04/24/2021 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Include your code as *text*.  Not as an unreadable image.

Comment: Hi - you have a 2nd SELECT statement embedded in, but unconnected to, the main SELECT statement. This is not valid SQL - what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty strange: if you want to join your subquery, you need to add a comma to the end of second line like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum, --< added a comma here
  (SELECT ems.vw_tal_patron.ptnid, ems.vw_tal_patron.firstname, ems.vw_tal_patron.lastname, ems.vw_tal_ptncard.lastmoddate, ems.vw_tal_userauditaction.action
   FROM ems.vw_tal_patron, ems.vw_tal_ptncard, ems.vw_tal_userauditaction 
   WHERE ems.vw_tal_patron.ptnid = Ems.vw_tal_ptncard.ptnid
   AND ems.vw_tal_ptncard.lastmoddate BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/24/2021 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('04/24/2021 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
   AND ems.vw_tal_userauditaction.action = 'CREATE USER')
WHERE EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum.anntypedesc = 'Sign-Up Date' 
AND EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum.anndate BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/24/2021 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE('04/24/2021 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');
```

But I don't see any join predicates between EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum and your subquery. Btw, it would be better to give an alias to your subquery, for example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum, --< added a comma here
  (SELECT ems.vw_tal_patron.ptnid, ems.vw_tal_patron.firstname, ems.vw_tal_patron.lastname, ems.vw_tal_ptncard.lastmoddate, ems.vw_tal_userauditaction.action
   FROM ems.vw_tal_patron, ems.vw_tal_ptncard, ems.vw_tal_userauditaction 
   WHERE ems.vw_tal_patron.ptnid = Ems.vw_tal_ptncard.ptnid
   AND ems.vw_tal_ptncard.lastmoddate 
            BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/24/2021 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
                and TO_DATE('04/24/2021 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
   AND ems.vw_tal_userauditaction.action = 'CREATE USER'
   ) SV --< added an alias "SV" (Subquery View)
WHERE EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum.anntypedesc = 'Sign-Up Date' 
  AND EMS.vw_tal_dailyptnsum.anndate 
          BETWEEN TO_DATE('04/24/2021 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') 
              and TO_DATE('04/24/2021 23:59:59', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Even if this join is what was intended, writing joins in this way is really bad practice and hasn't been recommended for decades. ANSI SQL join syntax should be used instead (INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, etc.)

Comment: @NickW partially agree, but there a lot of nuances in Oracle CBO I can't cover in a short comment. It's a big old question, you can google more about it "Native Oracle SQL vs ANSI SQL"

Comment: The days where the proper explicit JOIN operator would result in errors or bad plans in Oracle are long over. When it was introduced in 9i it did have problems, most where fixed in 10g and since 11g it does not have any more bugs than any other area in Oracle. It is really time to ditch the old syntax. For outer joins even Oracle recommends to get rid of the proprietary `(+)` operator

Comment: "The days where the proper explicit JOIN operator would result in errors or bad plans in Oracle are long over." - in short, no. It's really big question and I can't cover all aspects, but since we are just talking in "comments", I'll try to answer as short as I can:

Comment: 1/ As an Oracle performance tuning and troubleshooting engineer, I face such problems pretty often. And unfortunately, they will be appearing in near future, just because Oracle rewrites ANSI-style queries into own native syntax. Obviously, it adds extra complexity. Read more here: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/ansi-bug/ Or for example ANSI_REARCH transformation has appeared in 12.1.0.2(hints `ANSI_REARCH/NO_ANSI_REARCH`). Also it is a bit more difficult to hint such queries: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2020/03/22/ansi-hinting/.

Comment: Just open MOS and type "ANSI bug" and you will get a whole bunch of different new bugs, and I suggest you to subscribe to Jonathan Lewis' blog and to "Oracle Support Hot Topics" on MOS to get email with newly updated documents and bugs. For example, a few blog posts from Jonathan: 
https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/ansi-bug/
https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2019/06/22/ansi-bug-2/
https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2020/03/18/using-bug/
https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/ansi-expansion/
https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2020/01/27/ansi-flashback/

Comment: I see such bugs regularly in Support hot topics emails - I've just searched in my mailbox - last email with ANSI bug was 12th of April, just 17 days ago... So you can easily find that some bugs still haven't been fixed yet, moreover, such bugs still exist and continue to appear. NB: However, I recommend to use ANSI-style in most cases if you test it properly and it doesn't fail, just because of 2 main reasons:

Comment: 1. ANSI-style continue to develop, while oracle has stopped to develop own native syntax even before "full outer joins" and "partition join" - though Oracle has "Native full outer join" plan operation, it still hasn't native syntax for it. And things are even worse with partition-joins. Or think about `lateral()`: oracle had to allow it only because of ANSI `cross/outer apply`, though it was used internally.

Comment: 2. Even though a lot of old oracle specialists hate it (especially my collegues in perf.tuning and troubleshooting), ANSI style will continue to become more and more popular on Oracle databases. We can't ignore this fact. We should deal with it: more ANSI code -> more SRs -> more stable code. Of course, there are obvious exceptions: most critical high-performance queries.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I'm a bit tired to explain my opinion again. I did it many times. But if you want to get an opinion about this from such well-known experts like Jonathan Lewis, I'd suggest you to ask this question in Oracle-L mail list.