# How do we split a CLOB (with some lines with more than 32K characters) line by line via PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, split, clob

I am trying to split a huge CLOB which contains lines with more than 32K characters.

I tried to use this

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_cont, '[^'||chr(10)||']+', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
from data_tab where interface = 'Historical'
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(file_cont, '[^'||chr(10)||']+')) + 1
```

The table *data_tab* contains some files with pipe as a separator.
The column *file_cont* is a clob which contains the file we are interested in.
However, when I try to execute the above query, it looks like there is an infinite loop.

For information, the CLOB contains more than 600 lines.

What I want to do is to split the clob, line by line into distinct CLOB.
Do you know a query that can display this result without falling into an infinite loop?

EDIT : The file's size is 22MB.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `where` clause is applied after `connect by`, so it is better to write `(select * from data_tab where interface = 'Historical')` instead of `data_tab where interface = 'Historical'`, but still `regexp_replace`s are quite slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PL/SQL function to read the and split the value:

If you have the data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE clob_table AS TABLE OF CLOB;
```

Then the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION split_clob(
  p_value     IN CLOB,
  p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN clob_table PIPELINED
IS
  v_start  PLS_INTEGER;
  v_next   PLS_INTEGER;
  v_len    PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_start := 1;
  LOOP
    v_next := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( p_value, p_delimiter, v_start );
    v_len  := CASE v_next WHEN 0 THEN LENGTH( p_value ) + 1 ELSE v_next END - v_start;
    PIPE ROW ( SUBSTR( p_value, v_start, v_len ) );
    EXIT WHEN v_next = 0;
    v_start := v_next + LENGTH(p_delimiter);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

For the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB );

DECLARE
  v_value TABLE_NAME.VALUE%TYPE := EMPTY_CLOB();
BEGIN
  FOR ch IN 65 .. 68 LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
      v_value := v_value || RPAD( CHR(ch), 4000, CHR(ch) );
    END LOOP;
    IF ch < 68 THEN
      v_value := v_value || CHR(10);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  INSERT INTO table_name ( value ) VALUES ( v_value );
END;
/
```

Then the output of:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( s.column_value, 1, 10 ) AS value,
       LENGTH( s.column_value ) AS len
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY TABLE( split_clob( t.value, CHR(10) ) ) s
```

Is:

> | VALUE | LEN |
> | --- | --- |
> | AAAAAAAAAA | 40000 |
> | BBBBBBBBBB | 40000 |
> | CCCCCCCCCC | 40000 |
> | DDDDDDDDDD | 40000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efcce1dce186a05880f9c8fe67be4c92)*

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Then in my example I should do :

```

SELECT SUBSTR( s.column_value, 1, 10 ) AS value,
LENGTH( s.column_value ) AS len
FROM   data_tab t where t.interface = 'Historical'
CROSS APPLY TABLE( split_clob( t.file_cont, CHR(10) ) ) s

```
Am I right?

Comment: I tried with this query : select split_clob(file_cont,chr(10)) as tab from data_tab t where t.interface = 'Historical'.
I got columns with <Value Error>.

Comment: @Labedos Assuming that you are using Oracle 12 or later then `SELECT s.column_value FROM data_tab t CROSS APPLY TABLE( split_clob( t.file_cont, CHR(10) ) ) s WHERE t.interface = 'Historical'` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2dca7359cd740d62ec2fdd9ab0b8507b). If you are on Oracle 11 then use `CROSS JOIN` rather than `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11 and cross JOIN works. Thanks you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I have a special package for split and PCRE regular expressions:
https://github.com/xtender/XT_REGEXP

You can find this function in https://github.com/xtender/XT_REGEXP/blob/master/xt_regexp.pck

```sql
/**
 * Clob simple split
 */
  function clob_split_simple(p_clob in clob,p_delim in varchar2) 
  return clob_table pipelined is
    row clob;
    l_b number:=1;
    l_e number:=1;
    $IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.ver_le_11 $THEN
    $ELSE
    pragma UDF;
    $END
  begin
      while l_e>0
        loop
          l_e:=instr(p_clob,p_delim,l_b);
          pipe row(substr(p_clob,l_b,case when l_e>0 then l_e-l_b else length(p_clob)+length(p_delim)-l_b end));
          l_b:=l_e+length(p_delim);
        end loop;
  end clob_split_simple;
```

So you can either use this pipelined function:

```sql
select * 
from table(xt_regexp.clob_split_simple(:clob,chr(10));
```

or take this code as an example.

clob_table is just a `table of clob`:

https://github.com/xtender/XT_REGEXP/blob/master/types.sql

```
create or replace type clob_table as table of clob;
/
create or replace type date_table as table of date;
/
create or replace type number_table as table of number;
/
create or replace type varchar2_table as table of varchar2(4000);
/
create or replace type xml_table as table of xmltype;
/
```

**Update**: fixed a bug with long matches: dbms_lob.substr which returns varchar2, replaced with substr(clob) which return clob.

Comment: I get `NULL` output from this function [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5ae5accb4bdc377aef60d80aaf6bf5e).

Comment: This only works if the line length is 32767 or less and does not solve the OP's requirement.

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: This also does not work if the delimiter has multiple characters. `l_b:=l_e+1;` should be `l_b:=l_e+LENGTH(p_delim);`

Comment: nice catch and I see your changes :) fixed

Comment: Hello, what is the better solution in terms of performance?

Comment: @Labedos after MT0 changed his code they are almost equal :) except my one have `pragma UDF` which allows to run faster in sql, but you can add it into his code too

Comment: I tried with this query : select clob_split_simple(t.file_cont,chr(10)) as tab from data_tab t where t.interface = 'Historical'. I got column_value with <Value Error>

Comment: @Labedos you should do `select cl.* from data_tab t ,table(clob_split_simple(t.file_cont,chr(10))) cl`

Comment: You don't need to use legacy comma joins. From Oracle 12, you can use `CROSS APPLY` and before that you can use `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @MT0 Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320636/receiving-an-error-in-oracle-regarding-subquery/67320903?noredirect=1#comment119001974_67320903

Comment: I completely agree with [your statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67320636/receiving-an-error-in-oracle-regarding-subquery/67320903?noredirect=1#comment119002275_67320903) "However, I recommend to use ANSI-style in most cases if you test it properly and it doesn't fail"

Comment: @MT0 `table()` function(kokbf$) is one of the exceptions, because it blocks JPPD: http://orasql.org/2019/05/30/workarounds-for-jppd-with-view-and-tablekokbf-xmltable-or-json_table-functions/

Comment: though this query is pretty simple as of now, but sooner or later you can face this problem with CBO (there is also the old problem with default cardinality 8000 for such functions, hopefully it has some changes in latest releases with adaptive features and bind peeking for collections)

Comment: In my case should I use your request or MT0's one?

Comment: @Labedos it's up to you. as I said before they almost equal, so you can start with MT0's one, but then switch to mine in case of performance/optimizer problems

Comment: Thank you for both of you. I have another question : If my separator is an unix pipe "|", should I use '\|' or '|' as separator argument?

Comment: Just `|`, it doesn't require any escape character

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure SQL, by first converting data to `xmltype`, and then using `xmltable` to extract lines:

```
select x.line
  from data_tab d
     , xmltable('/d/x' passing xmltype('<d><x>'||replace(dbms_xmlgen.convert(d.file_cont),chr(10),'</x><x>')||'</x></d>')
                       columns line clob path '/') x
 where d.interface = 'Historical'
```