# PL SQL table function with bind variable as parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is a restriction of 4000 BYTES for string literal. I decided to build a table function that will separate by comma,colon, semicolon or pipe and outpu it as values in a column. Normaly I would do that with regexp_replace but there is no function for clob data type, am i right? is there a better way to do that?

The function  compiles and works if a pass some values.

I thought i could do something like this

```
variable patrik clob;
exec :patrik := 'abc,ghj,yut';

select * from patrik_split_clob(:patrik)
```

SQL Developer open a popup again to enter the values, I thought it could take the bind variable with the values just assigned and run.

I can use it that way as well, just curious.

there is another issue and with the following error

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "PATRIK_SPLIT_CLOB", line 28
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE patrik_split_value AS OBJECT (value VARCHAR2(4000));
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE patrik_split_table AS TABLE OF patrik_split_value;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION patrik_split_clob(p_clob CLOB)
RETURN patrik_split_table
AS
    v_result patrik_split_table := patrik_split_table();
    v_start_pos NUMBER := 1;
    v_end_pos NUMBER;
    v_length NUMBER := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(p_clob);
BEGIN
    LOOP
        v_end_pos := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(p_clob, ',', v_start_pos);
        IF v_end_pos = 0 THEN
            v_end_pos := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(p_clob, ':', v_start_pos);
        END IF;
        IF v_end_pos = 0 THEN
            v_end_pos := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(p_clob, ';', v_start_pos);
        END IF;
        IF v_end_pos = 0 THEN
            v_end_pos := DBMS_LOB.INSTR(p_clob, '|', v_start_pos);
        END IF;
        IF v_end_pos = 0 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        v_result.EXTEND;
        v_result(v_result.COUNT) := patrik_split_value(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_clob, v_end_pos - v_start_pos, v_start_pos));
        v_start_pos := v_end_pos + 1;
    END LOOP;
    v_result.EXTEND;
    v_result(v_result.COUNT) := patrik_split_value(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(p_clob, v_length - v_start_pos + 1, v_start_pos));
    RETURN v_result;
END;
```

what am i doing wrong? NUMBER should handle more than 99, is it because of v_start_pos := 1 ?

Comment: If you have oracle APEX installed in your db, then you could look at the package ```APEX_STRING``` - it has a function just for that

Comment: "SQL Developer open a popup again to enter the value" - are you running the select as a statement, or all three lines as a script?

Comment: Works for me in Oracle SQL Developer 20.2, using Run As Script. (I changed the "PL/SQL Developer" tag because you don't seem to be using it.) If the issue is with the popup prompt in SQL Developer, then your question doesn't need the function or the types, as you can reproduce the prompting issue with `select :patrik from dual;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

From a given start position in the string, you are finding

- the first comma;
- then, if there are no commas in the entirety of the remaining string, you are finding the next colon;
- then, if there are no commas or colons in the entirety of the remaining string, you are finding the next semi-colon;
- then, if there are no commas, colons or semi-colons in the entirety of the remaining string, you are finding the next pipe character;
- then you start looking again from the character you found.

If you have the string `a|b;c:d,e` then the first delimiter you match will be the comma and the first term will be `a|b;c:d` and the second term `e`; you will not split the string on multiple delimiters unless they are all in order of `,` then `:` then `;` then `|`.

Additionally:

- You do not need a type that is a table of objects; you can use `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)` or, if each term could be large than 4000 bytes you can use `TABLE OF CLOB`.
- You are using a non-pipelined function which will need to parse the entire string and generate the entire collection in memory; instead, you could use a pipelined function which will pipe rows as they are found and may not need to hold the entire collection in memory.

This is a function I created for an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415722/1509264) that splits by a single delimiter:

```sql
CREATE TYPE clob_table AS TABLE OF CLOB;

CREATE FUNCTION split_clob(
  p_value     IN CLOB,
  p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN clob_table PIPELINED
IS
  v_start  PLS_INTEGER;
  v_next   PLS_INTEGER;
  v_len    PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_start := 1;
  LOOP
    v_next := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( p_value, p_delimiter, v_start );
    v_len  := CASE v_next WHEN 0 THEN LENGTH( p_value ) + 1 ELSE v_next END - v_start;
    PIPE ROW ( SUBSTR( p_value, v_start, v_len ) );
    EXIT WHEN v_next = 0;
    v_start := v_next + LENGTH(p_delimiter);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

If you want to change it to multiple delimiters (and are sure that each term will be 4000 characters or less) then:

```sql
CREATE TYPE varchar2_4000_table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);

CREATE FUNCTION split_clob(
  p_value     IN CLOB
) RETURN varchar2_4000_table PIPELINED
IS
  v_start  PLS_INTEGER;
  v_next   PLS_INTEGER;
  v_delim  PLS_INTEGER;
  v_len    PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  v_start := 1;
  LOOP
    v_next  := 0;
    v_delim := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( p_value, ',', v_start );
    IF v_delim > 0 AND (v_next = 0 OR v_delim < v_next) THEN
      v_next := v_delim;
    END IF;
    v_delim := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( p_value, ':', v_start );
    IF v_delim > 0 AND (v_next = 0 OR v_delim < v_next) THEN
      v_next := v_delim;
    END IF;
    v_delim := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( p_value, ';', v_start );
    IF v_delim > 0 AND (v_next = 0 OR v_delim < v_next) THEN
      v_next := v_delim;
    END IF;
    v_delim := DBMS_LOB.INSTR( p_value, '|', v_start );
    IF v_delim > 0 AND (v_next = 0 OR v_delim < v_next) THEN
      v_next := v_delim;
    END IF;

    v_len := CASE v_next WHEN 0 THEN LENGTH( p_value ) + 1 ELSE v_next END - v_start;
    PIPE ROW ( SUBSTR( p_value, v_start, v_len ) );
    EXIT WHEN v_next = 0;
    v_start := v_next + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   split_clob('abc,ghj,yut')
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- |
| abc |
| ghj |
| yut |

and:

```
SELECT *
FROM   split_clob('a|b;c:d,e')
```

Outputs:

| COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |

*Note: In earlier Oracle versions you need to use `SELECT * FROM TABLE(split_clob(:varaible))` but in later versions the table collection expression syntax is optional and can be omitted (as you have done).*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vCx2O-Eh)

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less OK, you're just calling it in a wrong manner.

```
SQL> variable patrik clob;
SQL> exec :patrik := 'abc,ghj,yut';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table(patrik_split_clob(:patrik));

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc
ghj
yut

SQL>
```

Comment: `select * from patrik_split_clob(:patrik);` works in later Oracle versions. The table collection expression was changed from being mandatory to optional syntax (either in Oracle 12 or Oracle 18).

Comment: in my case it doesn't work in sql developer automatically. I need to pass the string in the popup window again when issuing the select. so creatr variable and assign the string first is not needed. i am curious why that happen because a I thing the function should take the variable with already assigned value

Comment: @Pato Run the worksheet as a script (F5) rather than running individual statements (ctrl-enter).